# Consequences of changing from xhtml strict to xhtml transitional?

Tags: xhtml, doctype

I've been assigned some tasks on a website built a few years ago. The site is built with the document type "xhtml strict" and those who built it have been careful to follow the standard.

Now the need has come up to use iframe on a few pages. Using the CMS they've chosen, it doesn't seem like there's an easy way to to change the document type for only these pages; the document type is set for all pages in one place.

Now there's two options:

- Change the doctype of the entire site to "xhtml transitional", which
  allows iframe.
- Keep the doctype and let the few pages be invalid.

I'd like to know the consequences of each option. Is there a downside to use transitional instead of strict? How bad is it to have a few pages that is invalid? I'm thinking in terms of SEO and such.

Comment: Google currently does not punish you for having invalid markup: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3KgrbiB1pc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching to Transitional will trigger [almost standards mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Gecko%27s_Almost_Standards_Mode) instead of standards mode. This may influence the rendering of your document. You would probably be better off switching to (X)HTML 5 instead.

Search engines don't publish their secret and frequently changing algorithms, so the impact on SEO would be speculative.

Comment: Thanks Quentin! Will a document that is valid "xhtml strict" also be valid html5 if I change the doctype?

Comment: Probably. There are a few differences. Use a validator to check.